# Flask-session not working in iphones because third-party cookies are blocked

Tags: ios, iphone, session-cookies, flask-session, third-party-cookies

My problem is that I have a web page with 2 domains, one for backend and another one for frontend, my backend is in flask, and i use flask-session module to create sessions, it works perfectly in almost everywhere but not in iphone, in mac works but not in iphone, so i realize that deactivating "Prevent Cross-Site Tracking" the session works perfectly in iphone, so the problem i see is that as my back and front have different domains it converts my session-cookie in third-party coockie, which is blocked in iphone, my question is ¿Does anybody knows a way to fix that? i don´t want to put my back and front in the same domain, either ask  users to disabled "Prevent Cross-Site Tracking".

thanks in advance

Comment: At the end i couldn´t figured it out so I had to change to json web token to keep a session.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with the following settings.

```
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True

app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = 'None'
```